# How is the Controlled Z Gate implemented?

Tags: quantum-gate

How are 2 qubit Controlled Z gates (1 control / 1 target) typically implemented? Do we seek physical realizations of this gate, or have an alternate decomposition?

Comment: This will generally be hardware dependent. Do you have a specific platform in mind?

Comment: No - I was curious if there was a typical realization with CNOTs / Pauli gates. I'd also be interested on which platforms CZs can be directly implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IBM QX architectures, the only entangling gate is the controlled not (CX), so controlled Z gates with control qubit $n$ and target qubit $m$ are decomposed into $CZ^n_m = H_m CX^n_m H_m$.

Although this is QX-specific, it demonstrates a principle that will likely hold on any architecture -- That the general method is to use a similarity transform to rotate Z onto the most conducive rotation axis for the hardware, perform that rotation, and rotate Z back into place.